# C++ Binary Tree, modifying root node, pointer to pointer to root node

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I realize the title isn't too descriptive so here are the details.  I'm implementing my own Binary Tree class in C++.  I have written a template Node class and template Binary Tree class already, for the most part, and am stuck on something. I created an empty binary tree (root node is null) and when I try to set that node it fails miserably. here is the code and more explanation:

```
template<class T> class Node
{
    T _key;
    Node<T> *_leftChild;
    Node<T> *_rightChild;

    public:
        Node();
        Node(T key);
        Node(T key, Node<T> *leftChild, Node<T> *rightChild);
        ~Node();

        bool hasLeftChild();
        bool hasRightChild();

        void setKey(T key);
        void setLeftChild(Node<T> *node);
        void setRightChild(Node<T> *node);

        T getKey();
        Node<T>* getLeftChild();
        Node<T>* getRightChild();

        bool compare(Node<T> *compareNode); // return true if this.Node < compareNode
};
```

Node implementation not really necessary.. ( I dont think ) it's quite long.

```
#include "Node.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class BinaryTree
{
    Node<T> *_root;

    public:
        BinaryTree();
        BinaryTree(Node<T> *root);
        ~BinaryTree();

        Node<T>* getRoot();
        void insert(Node<T> **root, Node<T> *node);
};

template<class T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree()
{
    this->_root = NULL;
}

template<class T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(Node<T> *root)
{
    this->_root = root;
}

template<class T>
BinaryTree<T>::~BinaryTree()
{
    // delete stuff
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* BinaryTree<T>::getRoot()
{
    return this->_root;
}

template<class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::insert(Node<T> **root, Node<T> *node)
{
    if(!*root)
    {
        *root = node;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
BinaryTree<int> *tree = new BinaryTree<int>();

Node<int> *root = tree->getRoot();
Node<int> **root1 = &root;

cout << tree->getRoot() << endl;
Node<int> *noChildrenNode = new Node<int>(2);
tree->insert(&root1, noChildrenNode);
cout << tree->getRoot() << endl;
```

Inserts current functionality is just supposed to replace the NULL root pointer to the node pointer passed in as a parameter.  The failing miserably part is since the pointer is a copy it isn't actually setting the root node.. but I can't seem to figure out how to set up a pointer to a pointer to the root node so it can be altered.. I've got to be close and any help will be MUCH appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got to include the exact text of any error messages.  "fails miserably" is not adequate.

I think you want

```
 root = node;
```

Not

```
 *root = node;
```

Because if root is null, using *root is a null pointer exception.

Comment: There aren't any text error messages because there isn't any syntax/compile or running errors.
When the insert method was as so: void BinaryTree<T>::insert(Node<T> *root, Node<T> *node), then yes you are correct it would be root = node / null pt
Now it is void BinaryTree<T>::insert(Node<T> **root, Node<T> *node) so that being a pointer to a pointer, we need *root = node.
It has to be a pointer to a pointer so that the pointer to the root node can be modified from inside the function.  The problem is that the address that the root pointer points to doesn't change outside of the insert function.

Comment: Does the root node ever become non-null?